# Webrtc does not work over other networks.. STUN,TURN Server Already Set up

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, stun

Problem: My webrtc works totally fine from localhost environment or in the same wifi, but it unfortunately fails over distinct networks. I have searched extensively about this subject across stackoverflow but none have provided me a working solution.

Platform: Android => Firefox or Chrome  (Android creates offer)

I have tried:
-Using stun:stun.l.google.com:19302 server
-Using public turn servers
-Hosting my own turn server through VPS and Coturn
-Hosting my own stun server similarly
-HAVE ALREADY VERIFIED my own stun/turn servers on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/.
They all return correct sfrlx and relay ice candidates, respectively.

If I run it on chrome, the console does not raise any errors. If I run it on firefox, however, the console does fire : "ICE FAILED, see about:webrtc for more details"

And here is my about:webrtc log
https://pastebin.com/jLHVFGxH

Some more tabular informations:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oInn0.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSGYx.png

My iceServer configuration:

```html
   var connection = new RTCPeerConnection({
                iceServers: [{
                        urls:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
                    },
                    {
    url: 'turn:64.227.18.138:3478',
    credential: '*****',
    username: '******'
}]
            })
```

Now on android side:

```html
   List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();

        iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer());
        iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:64.227.18.138:3478").setUsername("*****").setPassword("*******").createIceServer());
```

Comment: We are encountering the same issue. Over TURN (using coturn), connections browser to browser work, Android to Android work, but Android to browser will not also result in ICE FAILED. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @min-min-park I am also facing the same problem did you find the solution?